# Two players $A,B$ throw two dice....

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving, conditional-probability

Two players $A,B$ throw two dice.
A throw first, and they throw it in turns (i.e. $A,B,A,B,A...$).

If $A$ gets sum of $10$ at the dice he wins, if $B$ gets $9$ - he wins.
**What is the probability that $A$ thrown the dice last?**

I used this EQ: $$P(E|F)=P(E|FG)\cdot P(G|F)+P(E|FG^C)\cdot P(G^C|F)$$
$E$ = A got sum of $10$.
$F$ = The sum of the dice was $9$ or $10$.
$G$ = $B$ got $9$.

My result was $\frac{2}{5}$. I'm right?
And I need to find another way (i.e. not by this equation).
Can you give ideas how?

Thank you!!

Comment: For the "other way": Express it as an infinite series. $A$ can win on his first toss, or his second (third roll total), or his third, ...

Comment: @DavidMitra. I tried, but I get $\frac{3}{7}$... and it's not $\frac{2}{5}$... Thank you!

Comment: The way you are reading the question, it doesn't matter who threw the dice, whenever somebody gets a $9$ or $10$ the game stops.  In that case $A$ winning is $\frac{\frac 3{36}}{\frac 3{36}+\frac 4{36}}=\frac 37$.  That is not the same as the chance that $A$ threw last.

Comment: @RossMillikan, So how I fix it? How I use the formula right? Can you show me how to use it correctly? Thank you!

Comment: $P(A wins)=P(E)+P(E^cG^cE)+P(E^cG^cE^cG^cE)+\dots$ which says A wins either the first time he throws, or gets to throw a second and wins then, or gets to throw three times and wins, or ...  This is what David Mitra was hinting at.

Comment: @RossMillikan,I have to use this formula: $P(E|F)=P(E|FG)\cdot P(G|F)+P(E|FG^C)\cdot P(G^C|F)$ not the one that you wrote...

Comment: I don't see how to use your formula.  I think you want F to be "A didn't get 10 and B didn't get 9" which says the game goes on, but then you don't need G.  I don't know why you want $P(E|F)$-A winning is just E and if he wins the first time then F never happens.

Comment: @RossMillikan, You can change the events $E,F,G$... And now it's more clear, I'll need to calculate $P(E)$ bue I have to use Conditional Probability.

Comment: @RossMillikan, I'm still stuck, I don't know which events I should use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the chance that $A$ wins.  Then $B$ wins $1-p$.  $A$ can win by throwing $10$, or by throwing something else, having $B$ not throw a $9$, and then winning from start.  As the chance of a $10$ is $\frac 3{36}$ and a $9$ is $\frac 4{36}$, we have $p=\frac 3{36}+(1-\frac 3{36})(1-\frac 4{36})p$

Comment: Why: $B$ wins =  $1-p$??

Comment: And you don't have use the power of $n-1$?? Thank you!

Comment: Ross, my answer was right?

Comment: For the first, because one or the other wins eventually.  For the second, no you don't need powers, because after two misses you are back at the start.  It appears you read the question that if $A$ throws $9$, then $B$ wins.  I was reading it that if $A$ throws $9$, the game continues until either $A$ throws $10$ or $B$ throws $9$.  In that case I get $A$ wins $\frac 9{20}$

Comment: Thank you! Why do you put $p$ at the end? $p=\frac 3{36}+(1-\frac 3{36})(1-\frac 4{36})p$?

Comment: Because after both A and B miss, we are back at the start, so A will again win with probability $p$.  The terms on the right correspond to my third sentence.  The $\frac 3{36}$ is that A wins on the first throw.  The other term says A misses, then B misses, then A wins eventually (including the second throw).

Comment: Yes, it's $\frac{9}{20}$, you right!